# 20 amp to a 40 amp circuit

Tags: circuit-breaker

On the back of my house is the breaker box. It has an open 40AMP fuse (not connected to anything any more). There is also a 20AMP fuse connected to my shed. When the shed was originally built, it was only going to be used to hold junk and so a couple of incandescent light bulbs worked fine. Now I'd like to use the shed as a workshop. I'd like to be able to run a window AC unit (700w IIRC), several LED workshop lights (like the old fluorescent tubes but only LED instead), and some power tools, nothing crazy. Can I move switch the breakers in the breaker box so that I have the 40amps available to my workshop?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's more suited to https://DIY.stackexchange.com. It's not an electronics design question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not as a 20A circuit is likely run with 12 ga wire which will be unsuitable for your 40A circuit.  Doing what you propose is both dangerous and illegal.

Are you really using fuses?

Comment: Not fuses, breaker switches. Sounds like this isn't an area I should touch - I clearly don't know the jargon well enough. I'm not educated enough on this. Thanks jwh20.

Comment: Consult electrician if you don't  know wires gage. Breakers protect wires from overheating and burning your house.